# Creating a dynamic adjacency list for a graph, memory violations

Tags: c++, dynamic, graph, malloc, adjacency-list

I have to to create a dynamic adjacency list graph based off of a 2D array(40x20) of 0's and 1's. The graph will have an edge, if two elements of the array that are exactly 1 distance apart (up, down, left or right only, no diagonals) are both 1's, which would look like that: (Each vertex has an unique number equal to: (ROW)*(MAX_COLUMNS) + (COLUMN))

```
  0 1 2 3 4
0 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 1
2 1(1)0 1 1
3 0 1 0 1 0
4 1 1 0 1 0

Adjacencylist[(2*5)+1] = {6 , 10 , 16}
```

Etc.
So far I've managed to create a list for only one of the neighbours of a given vertex, but I've got no idea how to add the next neighbour to the neighbour before, nor do I know how to make it work on the edges of the graph(When there is only 2 or 3 neighbours) Here's the full code: https://ideone.com/r2JRrf , and below is just the part that is problematic to me.

```
struct Wierzcholek {
    Wierzcholek* next;
    int wartosc;
}
    Wierzcholek* p;
    Wierzcholek** TablicaList = new Wierzcholek * [LiczbaWierzcholkow];

    for (int i = 0; i < LiczbaWierzcholkow; i++)
        TablicaList[i] = nullptr;

    for (int i = 1; i < 40-1; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < 20-1; j++)
        {
            if (MacierzGrafu[i][j] == 0) continue;
            else 
            {
                if (MacierzGrafu[i - 1][j] == 1)
                {
                    p = new Wierzcholek;
                    p->wartosc = (((i-1) * 20) + j);
                    p->next = TablicaList[(i * 20) + j];
                    TablicaList[(i * 20) + j] = p;
                }
                /* Here are the algorithms for creating up,down and right neighbours,
                // however I'm unable to make them all work together 
                if (MacierzGrafu[i][j - 1] == 1)
                {
                    p = new Wierzcholek;
                    p->wartosc = ((i * 20) + j - 1);
                    p->next = TablicaList[(i * 20) + j];
                    TablicaList[(i * 20) + j] = p;
                }
                if (MacierzGrafu[i + 1][j] == 1)
                {
                    p = new Wierzcholek;
                    p->wartosc = (((i+1) * 20) + j);
                    p->next = TablicaList[(i * 20) + j];
                    TablicaList[(i * 20) + j] = p;
                }
                if (MacierzGrafu[i - 1][j - 1] == 1)
                {
                    p = new Wierzcholek;
                    p->wartosc = ((i * 20) + j + 1);
                    p->next = TablicaList[(i * 20) + j];
                    TablicaList[(i * 20) + j] = p;
                }
               /*
```

How should I steer the pointers to make the graph stable(and usable for DFS)?
On a sidenote, how do I give the function a formal parameter that is `Wierzcholek** Vertex`. Any help is greatly appreciated, as I'm fairly new to programming and only really beginning to understand the beautiful complexity of pointers and dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: Any reason you can't use `std::vector` here instead of bashing around with `new[]`? Whenever possible try and do this as a 1D structure but emulate the "2Dness" of it using `x + y * w` or something to that effect on your indexed lookups.

Comment: @tadman Yes, I can't use STL libraries as it's specified in the projects direction, I already transformed 2D into 1D but i still have a problem with the pointers.

Comment: "Can't use STL" is usually a very bad sign. Pointers are *nothing* but trouble in C++ due to a myriad of issues, but especially RIAA related. If you're not using `std::vector` for stuff like this because of some arbitrary decision and not a technical limitation, that's just making extra work for yourself, and likely creating huge, difficult to debug issues. Hope you survive this project.

Comment: If, for whatever reason, you're stuck using pointers, **write test code** to be sure you're doing this properly. Just running some test program over and over again isn't going to help. You need unit tests of the sort you can get with a tool like [catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2), though there are many, many other options. You want to be sure that this code works under a variety of use cases.

Comment: It would help to use English in the code.

Comment: @tadman ""Can't use STL" is usually a very bad sign." Not necessarily if you stick to "C with classes". As an anecdote, I have worked on an embedded project where STL could not be used because there was simply not enough RAM available for such a thing.

Comment: @kelvin the point of forbidding STL's was to make us thoroughly learn pointers and how they operate so I think it was pretty justified as it was only the first of many projects i had to finish that semester

Comment: @Ville Laitila I was a begginer back then, now I only try to write in english :)

Comment: @kelvin I'd argue that those aren't C++ courses. They're "C plus" courses, which is really to say *they should teach C first* then show how C++ takes that in entirely new directions. I know some platforms have little to no support for the Standard Library, but that list is getting shorter and shorter as implementations improve and as the definition of "minimal" hardware scales up gradually. C++ can be a pleasant language to work with, but a lot of university courses give *completely the wrong impression of C++* and do it a huge disservice.

Comment: @tadman "I'd argue that those aren't C++ courses. They're "C plus" courses" "but a lot of university courses give completely the wrong impression of C++ and do it a huge disservice." When I was in college, what we had were called data structure courses and we were also required to use raw pointers for graphs and trees, as learning how pointers work (and how they map to memory) was one of the main objectives.  Whether C or C++ was used for the rest was secondary (and there wasn't any "C" or "C++" course either by the way) and I think that it was for the better.

Comment: @tadman "I know some platforms have little to no support for the Standard Library, but that list is getting shorter and shorter" For reference, this was only a few years ago and we used a (relatively recent) industrial board with 64kB RAM total and 1kB RAM per thread (IIRC) running on an RTOS.  AFAICT the entire platform (mbed) was implemented as C++ without STL (and without e.g.: virtual methods and templates) and so was the many years-long project.  I wasn't a big fan of that, but I couldn't justify deviating from the platform/project standards either.

Comment: @kelvin True, but boards like that are getting more of an anachronism as things like ARM-based microcontrollers take hold at prices that are honestly borderline ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the part of code i commented actually works, so for whatever reason if you need a adjacency list for a simple rectangle Graph, that you want to later search with DFS or BFS you could use my code implemented here(I know the field of use of this code is not really broad but it may come handy to someone struggling in school/college like i did)[Also you would need to add some sort of restrictions for borders of this graph, or just make every "edge" as in GraphMatrix[0][k],GraphMatrix[k][0],GraphMatrix[MAX][k] and GraphMatrix[k][MAX] (k being an integer < MAX) a 0 because you might get memory leaks as the elements out of scope might be unaccesible to you]:

```
//GraphMatrix is rectangle matrix composed of 0's and 1's
struct Vertex {
    Vertex* next;
    int value;
}
    Vertex* p;
    Vertex** AdjacencyList = new Vertex * [NumberOfVertices];

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfVertices; i++)
        AdjacencyList[i] = nullptr;

    for (int i = 1; i < 40-1; i++)     // In this case 40 and 20 were the height and   
       for (int j = 1; j < 20-1; j++)  // width of my rectangular graph
        {
            if (GraphMatrix[i][j] == 0) continue;
            else 
            {
                if (GraphMatrix[i - 1][j] == 1)
                {
                    p = new Vertex;
                    p->value= (((i-1) * 20) + j);
                    p->next = AdjacencyList [(i * 20) + j];
                    AdjacencyList [(i * 20) + j] = p;
                }
                if (GraphMatrix[i][j - 1] == 1)
                {
                    p = new Vertex;
                    p->value= ((i * 20) + j - 1);
                    p->next = AdjacencyList [(i * 20) + j];
                    AdjacencyList [(i * 20) + j] = p;
                }
                if (GraphMatrix[i + 1][j] == 1)
                {
                    p = new Vertex;
                    p->value= (((i+1) * 20) + j);
                    p->next = AdjacencyList [(i * 20) + j];
                    AdjacencyList [(i * 20) + j] = p;
                }
                if (GraphMatrix[i - 1][j - 1] == 1)
                {
                    p = new Vertex;
                    p->value= ((i * 20) + j + 1);
                    p->next = AdjacencyList [(i * 20) + j];
                    AdjacencyList [(i * 20) + j] = p;
                }
```